# NGINX as SSL Proxy for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've got an Angular site and Tomcat web service application installed on the same Linux RH7 EC2 host. I'm trying to serve the web site from `/` and redirect anything at `/service` to my tomcat instance, both over SSL.

The static site serving over SSL is working fine. Also if I hit `http://mydomain:8080/mytomcatapp` that's working fine too. Trying to setup reverse proxying for the tomcat app by going `https://mydomain/service/mytomcatapp` however is resulting in 502 responses. The other samples I've seen have more fancy settings for headers etc, not sure if I need that, advice would be handy. Also my webservice at mytomcatapp takes get parameters too, so not sure if anything special is required there either.

**nginx conf snippet**

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name mydomain   ;
root /var/www;
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
    # index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri$args $uri/index.html /index.html =404;
}

location /service {
    proxy_pass http://mydomain:8080;
}

...
```

**tomcat server.xml snippet**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           proxyPort="443"
           scheme="https"
            />
```

Note: mydomain in the nginx conf has been swapped from my real domain (don't want to publish here). Also I have tried combinations of server.xml configuration with the `proxyName` attribute set but didn't seem to affect it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being the enhanced security posture of SELinux that was blocking proxying. See:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/

You need to set it to permissive mode by running the command: `setenforce 0`

For reference, my final location block in the nginx config is below for anyone else attempting, took a few goes to get right. Note that the trailing slashes on the `location` and `proxy_pass` variables are **very** important.

```
location /service/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have implemented certificate for SSL ?? If you want to use HTTPS you will need certificate.

Comment: SSL is configured and working correctly in NGINX for the web site as I mentioned in my post.